# Use recompose setStatic and connect it to redux (nextjs)

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, recompose

I am using following composition and was expecting `a` to be passed as a prop. It is undefined though.

How to fix it please?

```
import { setStatic, compose } from 'recompose'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

export const getInitialProps = function() {
  console.log(this.props.a);
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  a: url => dispatch({type: 'a'})
})

export default compose(
  connect(null, mapDispatchToProps),
  setStatic('getInitialProps', getInitialProps),
)
```

Comment: `this` is undefined or `a` is?

Comment: excellent question. this seems to be defined. props are not.

Comment: I think you are missing this binding in constructor, or you need to pass this inside getintialprops

Comment: Perhaps Change getInitialProps to arrow function and try. I think you are loosing this context in getInitialProps because it’s normal function

Comment: as arrow function even `this` disappears

Comment: How are you calling `getInitialProps`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is outcome of the investigation:
`getInitialProps` is called on server side which means that it is way before mounting to redux happens. Prop I was trying to inject was available to me in `componentDidMount` lifecycle